# Custom colormap in folium HeatMapWithTime

Tags: visualization, heatmap, folium

How can I use custom colormap with folium HeatMapWithTime ?
According to docs, **init** only got next parametres:

```
plugins.HeatMapWithTime(data, index=None, name=None, radius=15, min_opacity=0, max_opacity=0.6, scale_radius=False, use_local_extrema=False, auto_play=False, display_index=True, index_steps=1, min_speed=0.1, max_speed=10, speed_step=0.1, position='bottomleft')
```

I'd like to have more options to customize the view.